# Simple, efficient bilinear interpolation of images in numpy and python

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

How do I implement bilinear interpolation for image data represented as a numpy array in python?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found many questions on this topic and many answers, though none were efficient for the common case that the data consists of samples on a grid (i.e. a rectangular image) and represented as a numpy array. This function can take lists as both x and y coordinates and will perform the lookups and summations without need for loops.

```
def bilinear_interpolate(im, x, y):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)

    x0 = np.floor(x).astype(int)
    x1 = x0 + 1
    y0 = np.floor(y).astype(int)
    y1 = y0 + 1

    x0 = np.clip(x0, 0, im.shape[1]-1);
    x1 = np.clip(x1, 0, im.shape[1]-1);
    y0 = np.clip(y0, 0, im.shape[0]-1);
    y1 = np.clip(y1, 0, im.shape[0]-1);

    Ia = im[ y0, x0 ]
    Ib = im[ y1, x0 ]
    Ic = im[ y0, x1 ]
    Id = im[ y1, x1 ]

    wa = (x1-x) * (y1-y)
    wb = (x1-x) * (y-y0)
    wc = (x-x0) * (y1-y)
    wd = (x-x0) * (y-y0)

    return wa*Ia + wb*Ib + wc*Ic + wd*Id
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I was looking just for the same thing, and your implementation looks pretty good. I grasped basic usage, but can you please provide some advanced examples (with several coordinates) to make this answer even better?

Comment: @ffriend: $im$ is a 2D numpy array, and $x$ and $y$ are both ordinary python lists of doubles having the same length.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I also found that the code works pretty well with 2D NumPy arrays. However, one should care about indexes and image boundaries. If, for example, `im.shape == (10, 10)`, and `x == 9`, then `x0 == 9` and `x1 == x0 + 1 == 10`, which will produce `IndexError`. Simplest way to fix it is to extend image to have one extra column and one extra row (say, with values `im[:, -1]` and `im[-1, :]`). Though in most practical cases (like affine transformation that I came with) more advanced techniques should be used. Anyway, thanks for this nice example of powerful vectorization.

Comment: @ffriend: Thanks, have updated the code to check for out of range values.

Comment: Can this be used for images. For instance, if I wanted to stretch a 100x100 image to a 400x200 sized image? Is so, what would that code look like?

Comment: With this code, the edges can often be zero, because x (or y) will be equal to x0 and x1 after clipping. Any suggestions on how to deal with that? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @AlexFlint, thanks for posting this and I have a small suggestion.  This small diff in just the last line will make this compatible with 2D grids of D-dimensional values, i.e. [WxHxD], as in a D=3 rgb image or higher:

`return (Ia.T*wa).T + (Ib.T*wb).T + (Ic.T*wc).T + (Id.T*wd).T`

Let me know if you have any questions?  Thanks!

Comment: @AlexFlint I am looking at the wiki definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation and I am missing in your solution the devide by (y1-y0)*(x1-x0) what am I missing? is there a reason not to divide?

Comment: @ohadedelstain note that in the answer `y1 = y0 + 1` and `x1 = x0 + 1`, therefore `(y1-y0)*(x1-x0)` is always 1.

Comment: this function returns 0 for `bilinear_interpolate(np.ones((2, 2)), 1.0, 1.0)` which is incorrect based on my understanding of the intention

Comment: It's because 1. and 1. are boundary. you may add or subtract a small number `eps=1e-5` when x or y is boundary: `if x==0: x+=eps` and `if x==im.shape[1]-1: x-=eps`, same for y. Then it will work as expected.

Comment: There is a bug here. wa..wd need to be computed before applying clipping to {x0, x1, y0, y1} otherwise the boundary cases are incorrect.

Comment: Can we use x0=floor(x) and x1 = x0+1 , because we are assuming that pixel size will always be 1X1? Is this assumption always met in the image context?