# Python - Bilinear image interpolation

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I'm trying to write a Python function that takes an image as input and performs bilinear image interpolation to resize an image. I've had reasonable success, since the image does get resized, but the process introduces black holes in the output which I can't seem to figure out how or why they're there.

The questions I've seen haven't helped me much ([Simple, efficient bilinear interpolation of images in numpy and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729228/simple-efficient-bilinear-interpolation-of-images-in-numpy-and-python))

The code:

```
def img_interp(img, scale = 1.5):

    angle_rad = pi * angle_deg / 180.0;

    rows, cols, colours = img.shape

    n_rows = int(round(rows * scale, 0))
    n_cols = int(round(cols * scale, 0))

    enlarged_img = np.ones((n_rows, n_cols, colours))

    for i in range(n_rows - 1):
        for j in range(n_cols - 1):
            x_coord = j / scale
            y_coord = i / scale

            xc = int(ceil(x_coord))
            xf = int(floor(x_coord))
            yc = int(ceil(y_coord))
            yf = int(floor(y_coord))

            W_xc = xc - x_coord
            W_xf = x_coord - xf
            W_yc = yc - y_coord
            W_yf = y_coord - yf

           enlarged_img[i, j, :] = 255 - np.around(W_xc * (W_yc * img[yf, xf, :] + W_yf * img[yc, xf, :]) + W_xf * (W_yc * img[yf, xc, :] + W_yf * img[yc, xc, :]), 0)

    return enlarged_img
```

The image results:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ji0frbzcuyxd11u/results.png?m=

There are probably better ways to do this than what I've done, but I would really appreciate it if someone could have a look and tell me what I did wrong or what I still need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, may I recommend [scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom), [scipy.misc.imresize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html#scipy.misc.imresize) or [mahotas.zoom](http://mahotas.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#mahotas.imresize)? You get a choice of interpolation orders, with 1 being linear.

As to why it isn't working, if your x_coord or y_coord happen to be integer, then the weights will be zero.

Comment: Wouldn't only one of the weights be zero and the other weight = 1 then?

Comment: No: ceil(x_coord)=floor(x_coord), so xc-x_coord=0 AND x_coord-xf=0

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I'll take a look and post the fix when I find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use any one of the excellent image processing libraries available to Python?  For example, OpenCV has [cv2.resize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) which performs bilinear interpolation by default.  Scipy has [scipy.misc.imresize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html).

Comment: I have used them and they worked very well, but I'm doing a course on image processing and I'd like to make a function for myself to learn how the process works

Comment: And then there is [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), and several [interfaces to ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php).