# Two dimensional color ramp (256x256 matrix) interpolated from 4 corner colors

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

What I want to achieve is to programmatically create a two-dimensional color ramp represented by a 256x256 matrix of color values. The expected result can be seen in the attached image. What I have for a starting point are the 4 corner colors of the matrix from which the remaining 254 colors inbetween should be interpolated. While I had some success for interpolating the colors for one axis, the two-dimensional calculation provides me some bad headaches. While the image seems to have a non-linear color gradient, I would be happy with a linear one.

If you could give me some hints how to do this with numpy or other tools I`ll be more than thankful.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a specific formula for intrepolating the values ?

Comment: No, not really. What I tried was using scipy.interpolate.interp1d and http://www.alanzucconi.com/2016/01/06/colour-interpolation.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060379/python-bilinear-image-interpolation) looks relevant.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I have searched but missed it. jadsq provided a similar solution as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a super short solution using the [zoom function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html) from `scipy.ndimage`. I define a 2x2 RGB image with the intial colors (here random ones) and simply zoom it to 256x256, `order=1` makes the interpolation linear. Here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

im=(np.random.rand(2,2,3)*255).astype(np.uint8)

from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom
zoomed=zoom(im,(128,128,1),order=1)

plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(im,interpolation='nearest')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(zoomed,interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: output from the script]

Comment: I don't know where my previous comments ended up. Just wanted to thank you for this solution. Works very well and the trick with zooming is pretty handy! Thank you jadsq!

Comment: You're welcome. Your comments may have been removed regarding stackoverflow policy on "Thanks" comments, but don't worry : upvoting and accepting answers are enough to show your gratefulness :)

Comment: Just leaving this comment in case it confuses anyone else, the extra 1 in the zoom amount is just for the RGB values. This answer was super useful for what I needed anyway, thanks, just a shame the interpolation doesn't work in reverse :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very short way to do it with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows. There are also Python bindings. Anyway, just at the command line, create a 2x2 square with the colours at the 4 corners of your image, then let ImageMagick expand and interpolate up to the full size:

```
convert \( xc:"#59605c" xc:"#ebedb3" +append \) \
        \( xc:"#69766d" xc:"#b3b3a0" +append \) \
        -append -resize 256x256 result.png
```

[image]

The first line makes a 1x1 pixel of each of your top-left and top-right corners and appends the two side by side. The second line makes a 1x1 pixel of each of your bottom-left and bottom-right corners and appends them side by side. The final line appends the bottom row below the top row and enlarges by interpolation to 256x256.

If you want to better understand what's going on, here is the same basic image but scaled up using nearest neighbour rather than interpolation:

```
convert \( xc:"#59605c" xc:"#ebedb3" +append \) \
        \( xc:"#69766d" xc:"#b3b3a0" +append \) \
        -append -scale 20x20 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this easy solution, that definitely comes in handy if working on the command line and shell scripts. Very convenient!

Comment: Glad it works for you. You could also make a simple `bash` function if you do it often. Note that you can also give the colours in `rgb`, or in `rgba` (with transparency) or`hsl` instead of hex with `xc:'rgb(0,255,255)'`. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3):

Here are 3 ways to do this bilinear interpolation. The first version does all the arithmetic in pure Python, the second uses [PIL](https://python-pillow.org/) image composition, the third uses Numpy to do the arithmetic. As expected, the pure Python is significantly slower than the other approaches. The Numpy version (which was derived from code written by [Andras Deak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067311/andras-deak)) is almost as fast as the PIL version for small images, but for larger images the PIL version is noticeably faster.

I also tried using jadsq's scaling technique in PIL but the results were not good - I suspect that PIL's interpolation code is a little buggy.

If you wanted to create lots of these bilinear gradient images of the same size, the PIL technique has another advantage: once you've created the composition masks you don't need to rebuild them for every image.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' Simple bilinear interpolation 
    Written by PM 2Ring 2016.09.14
'''

from PIL import Image
from math import floor
import numpy as np

def color_square0(colors, size):
    tl, tr, bl, br = colors
    m = size - 1
    r = range(size)

    def interp_2D(tl, tr, bl, br, x, y):
        u0, v0 = x / m, y / m
        u1, v1 = 1 - u0, 1 - v0
        return floor(0.5 + u1*v1*tl + u0*v1*tr + u1*v0*bl + u0*v0*br)

    data = bytes(interp_2D(tl[i], tr[i], bl[i], br[i], x, y)
        for y in r for x in r for i in (0, 1, 2))
    return Image.frombytes('RGB', (size, size), data)

# Fastest
def color_square1(colors, size):
    #Make an Image of each corner color
    tl, tr, bl, br = [Image.new('RGB', (size, size), color=c) for c in colors]

    #Make the composition mask
    mask = Image.new('L', (size, size))
    m = 255.0 / (size - 1)
    mask.putdata([int(m * x) for x in range(size)] * size) 

    imgt = Image.composite(tr, tl, mask)
    imgb = Image.composite(br, bl, mask)
    return Image.composite(imgb, imgt, mask.transpose(Image.TRANSPOSE))

# This function was derived from code written by Andras Deak    
def color_square2(colors, size):
    tl, tr, bl, br = map(np.array, colors)
    m = size - 1
    x, y = np.mgrid[0:size, 0:size]
    x = x[..., None] / m
    y = y[..., None] / m
    data = np.floor(x*y*br + (1-x)*y*tr + x*(1-y)*bl + (1-x)*(1-y)*tl + 0.5)
    return Image.fromarray(np.array(data, dtype = 'uint8'), 'RGB')

color_square = color_square1

#tl = (255, 0, 0)
#tr = (255, 255, 0)
#bl = (0, 0, 255)
#br = (0, 255, 0)

tl = (108, 115, 111)
tr = (239, 239, 192)
bl = (124, 137, 129)
br = (192, 192, 175)

colors = (tl, tr, bl, br)
size = 256
img = color_square(colors, size)
img.show()
#img.save('test.png')
```

**output**

[image: bilinear gradient]

---

Just for fun, here's a simple GUI program using Tkinter which can be used to generate these gradients.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' Simple bilinear colour interpolation
    using PIL, in a Tkinter GUI

    Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/q/39485178/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2016.09.15
'''

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

DEFCOLOR = '#d9d9d9'
SIZE = 256

#Make the composition masks
mask = Image.new('L', (SIZE, SIZE))
m = 255.0 / (SIZE - 1)
mask.putdata([int(m * x) for x in range(SIZE)] * SIZE) 
maskt = mask.transpose(Image.TRANSPOSE)

def do_gradient():
    imgt = Image.composite(tr.img, tl.img, mask)
    imgb = Image.composite(br.img, bl.img, mask)
    img = Image.composite(imgb, imgt, maskt)
    ilabel.img = img
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    ilabel.config(image=photo)
    ilabel.photo = photo

def set_color(w, c):
    w.color = c
    w.config(background=c, activebackground=c)
    w.img = Image.new('RGB', (SIZE, SIZE), color=c)

def show_color(w):
    c = w.color
    newc = askcolor(c)[1]
    if newc is not None and newc != c:
        set_color(w, newc)
        do_gradient()

def color_button(row, column, initcolor=DEFCOLOR):
    b = tk.Button(root)
    b.config(command=lambda w=b:show_color(w))
    set_color(b, initcolor)
    b.grid(row=row, column=column)
    return b

def save_image():
    filetypes = [('All files', '.*'), ('PNG files', '.png')]
    fname = asksaveasfilename(title="Save Image",filetypes=filetypes)
    if fname:
        ilabel.img.save(fname)
        print('Saved image as %r' % fname)
    else:
        print('Cancelled')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Color interpolation")

coords = ((0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)) 
tl, tr, bl, br = [color_button(r, c) for r,c in coords]

ilabel = tk.Label(root, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
do_gradient()
ilabel.grid(row=1, column=1)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Save", command=save_image)
b.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank's for this comprehensive and thorough answer and the handy GUI code. As it looks like that you have very profound knowledge about numpy/PIL and image manipulation, I wanted to ask you if you could have a look at my follow up question where Spektre helped me a lot but I'm not quite sure if it can't be done with matrix/numpy operations (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489089/interpolating-elements-of-a-color-matrix-on-the-basis-of-some-given-reference-el/39506280#39506280). Anyway, thank you for your time and solution!

Comment: @hetsch: I'm fairly comfortable with PIL, but I don't know much about Numpy. The Numpy code above was actually written by Andras Deak, but I forgot to mention that earlier (sorry Andras!). I've had a brief look at the PDF you linked to in your new question, and I _think_ I understand their interpolation algorithm, but I don't know how to implement it efficiently with Numpy. But I will mention your new question to Andras next time I see him.

Comment: That would be really awesome! Thank's for spending your time and having a read on the paper.