# Classify users by colors?

Tags: python, colors, hex

I have a list of users. In this list, each user represented as an object that has some properties. One of this property is color. So, each user has some color. For example, the color of one user is `#f5abb5` and the color of the second user is `#f5abbb`. Both of them are the pink colors.

I need to classify my users by colors that they choose. These colors stored as hex codes. So, I think maybe Python has some tools that help to understand colors and say that `#f5abb5` and `#f5abbb` are pink colors? I found `colour` library but there is no way to understand colors like I need.

Another one way (not so good) that in a RGB color space, hex `#f5abb5` is composed of 96.1% red, 67.1% green and 71% blue. That means that red is main here and I can divide users like that. But the first way to understand that both colors are pink (or other colors are sky blue, and so on) is much better.

Comment: You may enjoy playing with the last program in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39515362/4014959) I wrote last year. A useful way to classify colors is by hue (as long as they aren't too pale or too dark). The standard `colorsys` module lets you convert RGB colors to HSV.; the "H" in HSV is hue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [webcolors](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webcolors/).

There's a function [`hex_to_name`](https://webcolors.readthedocs.io/en/1.7/contents.html#webcolors.hex_to_name) which meets your need perfectly.

> ```
> >>> hex_to_name(u'#ffffff')
> u'white'
> >>> hex_to_name(u'#fff')
> u'white'
> >>> hex_to_name(u'#000080')
> u'navy'
> >>> hex_to_name(u'#daa520')
> u'goldenrod'
> ```

### Edit:

Take care of the unmatched colors.

```
import webcolors as wc
import numpy as np

def get_approx_color(hex_color):
    orig = wc.hex_to_rgb(hex_color)
    similarity = {}
    for hex_code, color_name in wc.css3_hex_to_names.items():
        approx = wc.hex_to_rgb(hex_code)
        similarity[color_name] = sum(np.subtract(orig, approx) ** 2)
    return min(similarity, key=similarity.get)

def get_color_name(hex_color):
    try:
        return wc.hex_to_name(hex_color)
    except ValueError:
        return get_approx_color(hex_color)

print(get_color_name(u"#F5ABB5"))
# lightpink
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's really so close to the solution! But here a problem, I've got an error for `#f5abb5`: `ValueError: '#f5abb5' has no defined color name in css3`. I tried `hex_to_name(u'#F5ABB5', spec='html4')`, and no way as well.

Comment: Ahh then I think a manual approximation is needed. Wait a moment.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much!