# Bilinear interplotation function from scratch

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

As an HW for image processing course, I need to implement bilinear scaling of an image and I have been having difficulties. To make it clear, I have to write the function from scratch and not use openCV. I have finished the first part of the function and it looks like this. I cannot figure out the rest. I would appreciate any help.

```
def my_NN(input_image, scale):


    height = input_image.shape[0]
    width = input_image.shape[1]
    new_height = round(height*scale)
    new_width = round(width*scale)

    image_out = np.zeros((new_height,new_width),np.uint8)

    r = np.arange(float(new_height))
    c = np.arange(float(new_width))
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12729229/7666241

Comment: @KeKsBoTer already did, unfortunately, did not help much, I have to recreate the scaled image.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate: [Simple, efficient bilinear interpolation of images in numpy and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729228/simple-efficient-bilinear-interpolation-of-images-in-numpy-and-python)